# counting the number of sample bootstrap confidence intervals that contains the population median

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to count the number of bootstrap confidence intervals from 1000 replicates that contain the population median 0.693.

````
pop_median<-0.693
N<- 10000
set.seed(233)
data<-rexp(100,1)

result_vec <- vector(length=B)
lower_bound <- vector(length=B)
upper_bound<- vector(length=B)
count<-0
for (i in 1:1000){ 
  for(j in 1:N) {
    
    Boot_sample <- sample(data, size=length(Total), replace=TRUE)
    med <- median(Boot_sample)
    result_vec[j] <- med

  }
  result_vec[i]<- result_vec[order(result_vec)]
  lower_bound[i] <- result_vec[round(0.025*B)] #25 percentile
  upper_bound[i] <- result_vec[round(0.0975*B)] #97.5 percentile
  
  if(lower_bound<pop_median && upper_bound>pop_median){
    count<-count+1
  }
}
count
```
`

I have issues implementing the loop. I will be grateful for any assistance and suggestion to this.
````

Comment: You should run your code before posting. It fails at `result_vec <- vector(length=B)` because `B` is not defined and at `sample(data, size=length(Total), replace=TRUE)` because `Total` is not defined. Also the`median(data)` is 0.664022, not 0.693 because you are sampling from a small sample (only 100). Why not sample from the population? Also your percentiles seem to b 2.5% and 9.75% (not 97.5%).

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the value of **B<-1000** , and the **length(total)** should be **length(data)**. For the **population median** in question, we were advised to calculate the **P(x>M) =0.5** from the distribution in question and use the value of M as our population median; I didn't clarify that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it does not require a loop. First, the population you are sampling is an exponential distribution with rate=1. Given that information we can directly compute the median and estimate the 95% confidence interval for a sample of 100 taken from the population:

```
x <- seq(0, 5, length.out=100)
y <- dexp(x)
(md <- qexp(.5))
samples <- replicate(1000, rexp(100))
medians <- apply(samples, 2, median)
conf95 <- quantile(medians, probs=c(.025, .975))
round(conf95, 4)
#   2.5%  97.5% 
# 0.5137 0.9008
```

Now what happens if we bootstrap the confidence interval using a single sample of 100:

```
smpl <- rexp(100)
samplesb <- replicate(1000, sample(smpl, replace=TRUE))
mediansb <- apply(samplesb, 2, median)
conf95b <- quantile(mediansb, probs=c(.025, .975))
round(conf95b, 4)
#   2.5%  97.5% 
# 0.5016 1.0105
```

Notice that this confidence interval is wider (0.508897 vs 0.3632907) because we are using less information. Now how many of the bootstrap medians fall within each interval:

```
sum(mediansb >= conf95[1] & mediansb <= conf95[2])   # Population
# [1] 911
sum(mediansb >= conf95b[1] & mediansb <= conf95b[2]) # Bootstrap from sample
# [1] 960
```

The bootstrap interval includes a bit more than 95% since there are fewer distinct medians. The population interval includes fewer than 95% because it assumes that any any value in the population has an equal chance of being selected, not just 100 of the values.

```
length(unique(mediansb))
# [1] 116
length(unique(medians))
# [1] 1000
```

Finally, it may be useful to plot the results:

```
plot(x, y, type="l")
points(md, .5, col="red", cex=2)
arrows(conf95[1], .52, conf95[2 ], .52, length=.05, angle=90, code=3, lwd=1, col="red")
arrows(conf95b[1], .48, conf95b[2 ], .48, length=.05, angle=90, code=3, lwd=1, lty=1, col="blue")
```

[image: Plot]